# Should all related data be stored in a single shard if we use sharding to scale out relational databases?

Tags: mysql, database, scalability, rdbms, sharding

If we have multiple shards storing subsets of data in a scaled out relational database, how are relationships managed? Do all the related data in different tables for an entity be in the same shards? Or can we have relationships between data in different shards? How are they managed?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This question is far too broad and opinion based to be a fit here.

Comment: Short answer:  Yes, all data for relationships must be stored on the same shard.  Without using federated tables (DON'T DO THIS) there are no cross shard joins possible.  You could query each of the shards and coordinate the results in the proper tier, but your memory usage will be ridiculous. And don't even try inserts and updates across relationships.  You are better off understanding your data model and sharding the whole thing.

Comment: For further discussion, tell us about your application.  We should be able to explain what table(s) would best be split across multiple servers, and what tables need to be either duplicated or put on yet-another server.